# Cleaner way to awk this line

Tags: bash, awk, printing

I have the following data (bottom) in a text file.  I'm using awk to change the line into a column but man it's messy.

```
cat 5_lines.txt |awk -F\' '{print $1,"\n" "\n" $2,"\n" $3,"\n" $4,"\n" $5,"\n" $6,"\n" $7,"\n" $8,"\n" $9,"\n" $10,"\n" $11,"\n" $12,"\n" $13,"\n" $14,"\n" $15,"\n" $16,"\n" $17,"\n" $18,"\n" $19,"\n" $20,"\n" $21,"\n" $22,"\n" $23,"\n" $24,"\n" $25,"\n" $26,"\n" $27,"\n" $28,"\n" $29,"\n" $30,"\n" $31,"\n" $32,"\n" $33,"\n" $34"\n"}'|sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/,//g'
```

I'd appreciate some suggestions for shortening the awk portion of this command.  Thank you in advance.

####Expected Output

```
BBBB 4575 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.191    
part = TBD Part    
model = TBD Model    
serial = TBD Serial    
wpn = TBD WPN    
feature = 0    
mods =    
date = 0-00-00 00:00:00    
hours = 0    
key1 = 0    
key2 = 0    
key3 = 0    
key4 = 0    
key5 = 0    
key6 = 0    
key7 = 0    
key8 = 0    
14

BBBB 4576 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.121    
part = TBD Part    
model = TBD Model    
serial = TBD Serial    
wpn = TBD WPN    
feature = 0    
mods =    
date = 0-00-00 00:00:00    
hours = 0    
key1 = 0    
key2 = 0    
key3 = 0    
key4 = 0    
key5 = 0    
key6 = 0    
key7 = 0    
key8 = 0    
14

BBBB 4578 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.162    
part = TBD Part    
model = TBD Model    
serial = TBD Serial    
wpn = TBD WPN    
feature = 0    
mods =    
date = 0-00-00 00:00:00    
hours = 0    
key1 = 0    
key2 = 0    
key3 = 0    
key4 = 0    
key5 = 0    
key6 = 0    
key7 = 0    
key8 = 0    
14

BBBB 4580 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.179    
part = TBD Part    
model = TBD Model    
serial = TBD Serial    
wpn = TBD WPN    
feature = 0    
mods =    
date = 0-00-00 00:00:00    
hours = 0    
key1 = 0    
key2 = 0    
key3 = 0    
key4 = 0    
key5 = 0    
key6 = 0    
key7 = 0    
key8 = 0    
14

BBBB 4581 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.15    
part = TBD Part    
model = TBD Model    
serial = TBD Serial    
wpn = TBD WPN    
feature = 0    
mods =    
date = 0-00-00 00:00:00    
hours = 0    
key1 = 0    
key2 = 0    
key3 = 0    
key4 = 0    
key5 = 0    
key6 = 0    
key7 = 0    
key8 = 0    
14
```

#

Raw Data

```
BBBB 4575 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.191  part = TBD Part  model = TBD Model  serial = TBD Serial  wpn = TBD WPN  feature = 0  mods =  date = 0-00-00 00:00:00  hours = 0  key1 = 0  key2 = 0  key3 = 0  key4 = 0  key5 = 0 key5 = 0  key6 = 0  key7 = 0  key8 = 0  14    
BBBB 4576 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.121  part = TBD Part  model = TBD Model  serial = TBD Serial  wpn = TBD WPN  feature = 0  mods =  date = 0-00-00 00:00:00  hours = 0  key1 = 0  key2 = 0  key3 = 0  key4 = 0  key5 = 0 key5 = 0  key6 = 0  key7 = 0  key8 = 0  14    
BBBB 4578 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.162  part = TBD Part  model = TBD Model  serial = TBD Serial  wpn = TBD WPN  feature = 0  mods =  date = 0-00-00 00:00:00  hours = 0  key1 = 0  key2 = 0  key3 = 0  key4 = 0  key5 = 0 key5 = 0  key6 = 0  key7 = 0  key8 = 0  14    
BBBB 4580 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.179  part = TBD Part  model = TBD Model  serial = TBD Serial  wpn = TBD WPN  feature = 0  mods =  date = 0-00-00 00:00:00  hours = 0  key1 = 0  key2 = 0  key3 = 0  key4 = 0  key5 = 0 key5 = 0  key6 = 0  key7 = 0  key8 = 0  14    
BBBB 4581 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.15  part = TBD Part  model = TBD Model  serial = TBD Serial  wpn = TBD WPN  feature = 0  mods =  date = 0-00-00 00:00:00  hours = 0  key1 = 0  key2 = 0  key3 = 0  key4 = 0  key5 = 0 key5 = 0  key6 = 0  key7 = 0  key8 = 0  14
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The awk command uses `'` as a field separator yet that character does not appear in your sample input.  The sed command removes `[` yet that character does not appear in the input either.  _Please show clearly what your real input is and what your desired output is._

Comment: They must have been removed by the administrator.  The line are like this:BNSF 4575 10.145.181.191 ['part    = TBD Part', 'model   = TBD Model', 'serial  = TBD Serial', 'wpn     = TBD WPN', 'feature = 0', 'mods    = ', 'date    = 0-00-00 00:00:00', 'hours   = 0', 'key1    = 0', 'key2    = 0', 'key3    = 0', 'key4    = 0', 'key5    = 0', 'key6    = 0', 'key7    = 0', 'key8    = 0', '14']

Comment: If you see my original post you'll see I awk the line into a column but the awk part is cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not insisting on awk this may be a better option

```
cat yourfile.txt  | tr '[' ',' | tr -d "['\]]"  | sed 's/, /\n/g'
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i was looking for.  Can you explain why the comma is in there?

Comment: do you still need me to explain?

Comment: in your input data I repace [ with , to make it all comma delimited and then in next "tr" I delete ' and also ] so it all looks consitent and then you see that all fields are separated by <, > and I replace it with new lines

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Given your newly posted expected output:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    delete f
    nf=1
    for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
        if ($(i+1) == "=") {
            nf++
        }
        f[nf] = (f[nf]=="" ? "" : f[nf] OFS) $i
    }
    f[++nf] = $i

    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        print f[i]
    }
    print ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
BBBB 4575 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.191
part = TBD Part
model = TBD Model
serial = TBD Serial
wpn = TBD WPN
feature = 0
mods =
date = 0-00-00 00:00:00
hours = 0
key1 = 0
key2 = 0
key3 = 0
key4 = 0
key5 = 0
key5 = 0
key6 = 0
key7 = 0
key8 = 0
14

BBBB 4576 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.121
part = TBD Part
model = TBD Model
serial = TBD Serial
wpn = TBD WPN
feature = 0
mods =
date = 0-00-00 00:00:00
hours = 0
key1 = 0
key2 = 0
key3 = 0
key4 = 0
key5 = 0
key5 = 0
key6 = 0
key7 = 0
key8 = 0
14

BBBB 4578 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.162
part = TBD Part
model = TBD Model
serial = TBD Serial
wpn = TBD WPN
feature = 0
mods =
date = 0-00-00 00:00:00
hours = 0
key1 = 0
key2 = 0
key3 = 0
key4 = 0
key5 = 0
key5 = 0
key6 = 0
key7 = 0
key8 = 0
14

BBBB 4580 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.179
part = TBD Part
model = TBD Model
serial = TBD Serial
wpn = TBD WPN
feature = 0
mods =
date = 0-00-00 00:00:00
hours = 0
key1 = 0
key2 = 0
key3 = 0
key4 = 0
key5 = 0
key5 = 0
key6 = 0
key7 = 0
key8 = 0
14

BBBB 4581 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.15
part = TBD Part
model = TBD Model
serial = TBD Serial
wpn = TBD WPN
feature = 0
mods =
date = 0-00-00 00:00:00
hours = 0
key1 = 0
key2 = 0
key3 = 0
key4 = 0
key5 = 0
key5 = 0
key6 = 0
key7 = 0
key8 = 0
14
```

Note that the first loop in the script could just do the `print`s - the `f[]` array is only used to stored the fields (output lines) so they're available to you if you want to do anything additional with the fields after they have been identified.

---

EDIT: I see from one of your comments that your input format is actually NOT what you have posted in your question. It instead looks like this:

```
$ cat file
BNSF 4575 10.145.181.191 ['part = TBD Part', 'model = TBD Model', 'serial = TBD Serial', 'wpn = TBD WPN', 'feature = 0', 'mods = ', 'date = 0-00-00 00:00:00', 'hours = 0', 'key1 = 0', 'key2 = 0', 'key3 = 0', 'key4 = 0', 'key5 = 0', 'key6 = 0', 'key7 = 0', 'key8 = 0', '14']
```

That makes the solution MUCH simpler:

```
$ awk -F"', '" -v OFS='\n' -v ORS='\n\n' '{sub(/ \[\047/,OFS,$1); sub(/\047\]/,"",$NF)}1' file
BNSF 4575 10.145.181.191
part = TBD Part
model = TBD Model
serial = TBD Serial
wpn = TBD WPN
feature = 0
mods =
date = 0-00-00 00:00:00
hours = 0
key1 = 0
key2 = 0
key3 = 0
key4 = 0
key5 = 0
key6 = 0
key7 = 0
key8 = 0
14
```

It's always best when posting a question to show what your data really looks like rather than something different.

Comment: You're right, I should have been more descriptive.    Below is the output I'm getting by creating a tst.awk file then running it with the syntax you provided. ( I didn't post it initially because the output was too large for this editor.)  # awk -f tst.awk tmp/file.out
BBBB 4575 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.191 BBBB 4576 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.121
part = TBD Part part = TBD Part

Comment: Looking at my original post, you'll find five lines that start with BBBB.  Those five lines are in a file.  When I use your example, the first output is correct, but the second, third, fourth and fifth or not.  So instead of having BBBB 4575 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.191, I get BBBB 4575 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.191 BBBB 4576 XXX.YYY.ZZZ.121 on the same line.  So it outputs them on the same line.  The last line has all five BBBB entries on the same line.

Comment: Ed, your updated awk script gives me the output I was expecting.  Thank you for the extra effort.

Comment: I see now that the input in your question isn't actually what your input looks like. I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

give this sed one-liner a try:

```
sed -r 's/\S+\s*$/\n&/;s/\S+\s=/\n&/g' file
```

this line gives you the expected output.